# Use DateTime format in a class but restrict time tokens

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, formatting

I have a peculiar problem I want to solve. I have written a `MonthYear` class which essentially maintains a `DateTime` object behind the scenes and only allows methods/properties for month and year portion of the `DateTime`. Everything is working fine.

Now I have another requirement. I want to allow anyone using my class to use `ToString` method using date tokens but I want to only format the month/year tokens i.e. M, MM, MMM, MMMM, y, yy, yyy, yyyy, yyyyy and treat other tokens like m or t as literals.

Is it possible to do such a thing without writing my own parser/tokenizer?

**EDIT:** My Question is a bit difficult to understand I guess.

Here is a simpler form. Suppose I extend the `DateTime` class and I want to override `ToString` method in such a way that it gets me the following output:

```
DateTimeEx d = new DateTimeEx(2015, 6, 9);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("dd MM yy")); // dd 06 15
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH mm tt")); // dd Jun 2015 HH mm tt
```

I want to ignore every token except the ones I mentioned above. I hope this helps in making the question simpler.

I don't need help writing a parser method which only allows the above mentioned tokens. I only need to know is there a way this can be done with something built in.

Comment: _Is it possible.._ Have you tried it first? Can you please be more specific by the way? Also show `MonthYear` class as well.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your request. Could you give an example of what data is coming in and what data you are expecting out from your toString method?

Comment: @Soner & Fudztown: Sorry for the confusing question. Please see the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime d = new DateTime(2015, 6, 9);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("dd MM yy")); // dd 06 15
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH mm tt")); // dd Jun 2015 HH mm tt

var regex = new Regex("[yY]+|[M]+");
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace("dd MM yy", m => d.ToString(m.Value)));
Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace("dd MMM yyyy HH mm tt", m => d.ToString(m.Value)));
```

output

```
09 06 15
09 Jun 2015 00 00 AM
dd 06 15
dd Jun 2015 HH mm tt
```

a regex is used to find only the month/year format in format string. matches are used to format a datetime and result of formatting replaces a part of format string

Comment: This will not handle the case when the year and month format specifiers are escaped.

Comment: Why I never thought of regex for solving this problem! I was so intent on solving this through IDateFormatInfo etc that I completely forgot the KISS priniciple. This is a pretty elegant solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @juharr, i'm not sure i understood you. what do you mean by escaped? can you give an example of format string, please?

Comment: @ASh a format string of "\y" should result in the output of "y" instead of say "15".  You just need to make your regex make sure the values are not preceded by a "\".

Comment: @Yogesh True, but on top of making sure to not include escaped characters you also have to make sure to unescape them correctly.  So something like "\d \yy" shoudl give you "d y15" because the d and first y were escaped while the second y was not.

Comment: Yes. I figured that just now. Deleted my previous comment for the same reason.

Comment: @Yogesh, `var regex = new Regex(@"\\*[yY]+|\\*[M]+");` should make datetime handle all escaped months and years properly, i think

Comment: ASh, juharr point is correct. The above solution will handle \M but not \MM as it will treat the MM's second M as a token. But DateTime does that too, so it's expected behavior. :)

Answer (score -2):

I would overwrite the `ToString([arg1])` and just call the base in the overload and beforehand filter arg1 and remove all that doesn't fit ur pattern.

Comment: Sorry, It didn't make much sense to me. Can you please elaborate? Do you mean to say I should escape every token except the ones I need before passing to base ToString?

Comment: Correct Sr for my bad English